# What is this blue v that pops up when I open QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Everytime I open QGIS a blue v pops up. I have tried downloading version 3.12 and 3.14 and both of them have the blue v. I even tried uninstalling and redownloading version 3.14 to see if it would go away. I can pick it up and move it around. It doesn't seem to get in the way when I work, but I'm just curious what it means.  [image: This is a screenshot of when I open a new project in QGIS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used by Street View plugin which is enabled in your screen. If you uninstall, or disable the plugin from the plugin manager, it should disappear after restarting QGIS.